# Is there a way to detect type of keyboard on Window Mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I would like to be able to detect which type of keyboard a WM phone has, either 12-key or QWERTY to dynamically change the UI of my application.

Is there a way to detect this reliably?

Managed code solutions preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the (compact) framework for doing this.

I know Symbol had an API call in their SDK for detecting this in devices which supported multiple keyboard options. That's the nearest I've seen. Sorry, nothing generic.